# Reduce Numbers in Javascript Paigination and add Next and Previous

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I'm using a JavaScript Pagination to great success, however I have a few issues that I would love to sort.

If you have lots of "post", the pagination keeps adding numbers to the bottom of the screen but what im trying to code is 1 2 3 .... 9, 10 etc. Also, trying to have a highlighter, so you know which page you are on and also a next and previous. Any help would be appreciated. Code below:

**Paginate.js**

```
(function($){

       $.fn.customPaginate = function(options)
       {
           var paginationContainer = this;
           var itemsToPaginate;


           var defaults = {

                itemsPerPage : 6

           };

           var settings = {};

           $.extend(settings, defaults, options);

           var itemsPerPage = settings.itemsPerPage;

           itemsToPaginate = $(settings.itemsToPaginate);
           var numberOfPaginationLinks = Math.ceil((itemsToPaginate.length / itemsPerPage));

           $("<ul></ul>").prependTo(paginationContainer);

           for(var index = 0; index < numberOfPaginationLinks; index++)
           {
                paginationContainer.find("ul").append("<li>"+ (index+1) + "</li>");
           }

           itemsToPaginate.filter(":gt(" + (itemsPerPage - 1)  + ")").hide();

           paginationContainer.find("ul li").on('click', function(){

                var linkNumber = $(this).text();

                var itemsToHide = itemsToPaginate.filter(":lt(" + ((linkNumber-1) * itemsPerPage)  + ")");
                $.merge(itemsToHide, itemsToPaginate.filter(":gt(" + ((linkNumber * itemsPerPage) - 1)  + ")"));
                itemsToHide.hide();
                $('body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
                var itemsToShow = itemsToPaginate.not(itemsToHide);
                itemsToShow.show();
           });

       }

}(jQuery));
```

**Custom.js**

```
(function($){

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".pagination").customPaginate({

            itemsToPaginate : ".post"

        });

    });

})(jQuery)
```

Comment: you want Next Previous instead of Numbers ?

Comment: I'm trying to implement a bit of both to be honest @CY5